# Toggle a boolean server value using updateChildValues function

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Code:

```
database.child("\(groupChatId)_A").updateChildValues(["isLocked" : FirebaseDatabase.ServerValue.toggleBool()])
```

The `toggleBool()` is made up. Can I perform such action without the need to read and write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only atomic read-and-write operation that exists on the Realtime Database server is `increment(...)`. There is no operation to toggle a boolean value, so you'll have to [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) to perform the read-and-write in your application code.